# Type and size of a bitfied field

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang

This code works in MSVC and warns in Clang:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Bob {
    unsigned long long foo           : 10;
    unsigned long long bar            : 10;
};
int main()
{
    Bob b{};
    auto a = b.foo;
    static_assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(uint64_t), "wat");
    printf("%llx", a);
    printf("%llx", b.foo);
}
```

Warning:

```
<source>:15:17: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned long long' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        printf("%llx", b.foo);
                ~~~~   ^~~~~
                %x
```

Which is right?

https://godbolt.org/z/PGbr9qKEW

Comment: Bitfield has lot of stuff compiler-dependant (not even sure the `static_assert` is guaranteed to pass).

Comment: @Jarod42 the `static_assert` is wrong. Should be `sizeof(unsigned long long)`. That `unsigned long long` and `uint64_t` are the same size is just a happy accident. Note: Under 64bit unix systems `uint64_t` is usually `unsigned long`.

Comment: I'm more concerned that `auto a` is using `unsigned long long` while `b.foo` appears to be `int`. Imho both `printf` should warn or none. Having only one warning sounds like a compiler bug for sure.